# Trying to find the min, max and avg of this array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function minMaxAvgArray(arr){
  var min = arr[0];
  var largest = arr[0];
  var sum = arr[0];
  
  for (var i=0;i<arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i]<min){
    min=arr[0];
    }
    if (arr[i]>largest){
      largest=arr[0];
    }
    
    sum += arr[i];
      
    }
  return [min, largest, sum/=arr.length];
}
y = minMaxAvgArray([-2,3,4,5]);
console.log(y);
```

I'm trying to find the min,max and avg of the given array, every time I run this code the output is always "(-2, -2 2) can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: it's wrong.if (arr[i]<min){ min=arr[0];} it should be like this. if (arr[i]<min){ min=arr[i];}

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```js
function minMaxAvgArray(arr){
  var min = arr[0];
  var largest = arr[0];
  var sum = 0;
  
  for (var i=0;i<arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i]<min){
    min=arr[i];
    }
    if (arr[i]>largest){
      largest=arr[i];
    }
    
    sum += arr[i];
      
    }
  return [min, largest, sum/=arr.length];
}
y = minMaxAvgArray([-2,3,4,5]);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: I think you can accept my answer if it is useful. ;)

Comment: See stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, please.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to simplify your code with separated functions, something like:

```js
const data = [-2, 3, 4, 5];

const sum = (d) => d.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
const avg = (d) => (sum(d) / d.length) || 0;
const max = (d) => Math.max(...d.map(v => v));
const min = (d) => Math.min(...d.map(v => v));

const result = [min(data), max(data), avg(data)];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some indices to `1` instead of zero and start the loop from index one, because you take the values from index zero ass start value.

```js
function minMaxAvgArray(arr) {
    var min = arr[0];
    var largest = arr[0];
    var sum = arr[0];

    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {      // iterate from 1 bc 0 is start value
        if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];         // assign index i
        if (arr[i] > largest) largest = arr[i]; // assign index i
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return [min, largest, sum /= arr.length];
}

const y = minMaxAvgArray([-2, 3, 4, 5]); // declare variable
console.log(y);
```